# Connect impala with odbc and php pdo, string fields are empty

Tags: php, pdo, odbc, impala

When I use odbc only, all run successfully

```
$dsn = "DSN=DingdongImpala;host=172.168.1.100;port=21050;database=mmdb;";
$user = '';
$password = '';
$conn = odbc_connect($dsn, $user, $password);
$result = odbc_exec($conn, "select succount,failedcount,appid from t_mm_acc_date limit 1");
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

The result is:

```
Array
(
    [succount] => 0          //int
    [failedcount] => 1       //int
    [appid] => 202361        //string
)
```

But when I use pdo to access odbc, the String type fields are all empty

```
$dsn = "odbc:DSN=DingdongImpala;Host=172.168.1.100;Port=21050;database=mmdb;";
$user = '';
$password = '';
$cnx = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$result = $cnx->query("select succount,failedcount,appid from t_mm_acc_date limit 1");
print_r($result->fetchObject());
```

The result is:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [succount] => 100       //int
    [failedcount] => 0      //int
    [appid] =>              //string, empty
)
```

I tried a lot of cases, as long as I select String field from impala, the result will be empty, But int fields are normal.
My system environment:

```
centos 6
PHP 5.3.6
php-odbc-5.3.3
unixODBC-2.2.14
ClouderaImpalaODBC-2.5.29.1009-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same issue, as workaround I'm casting the string fields to varchar, like this:

```
select succount, failedcount, cast(appid as varchar(255)) from t_mm_acc_date limit 1
```